# Javascript does not work in asp.net content page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to display the javascript date time picker in a textbox on the content page, that is derived from the master page, but the datetime picker is not getting displayed.
    This is my content page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Datepicker.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="Datepicker.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dp').datepicker();
});
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dp1').datepicker();
});
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="From"></asp:Label>&nbsp;
    <input id="dp" type="text" runat="server"/>&nbsp;
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="To"></asp:Label>&nbsp;
    <input id="dp1" type="text" runat="server" />&nbsp;
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Search" onclick="Button1_Click" />
<asp:GridView ID="gvdetails" runat="server">
</asp:GridView>
</asp:Content>
```

Note: This works without the master page,but when I add it in a content page,it does not work.Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When ASP is served through IIS, all the `runat="server"` elements are given a unique name.

In order to find this name use the `<%= %>` syntax with the `ClientID` of your object.  In your case it would be:

```
$('#<%=dp1.ClientID%>').datepicker();
```

Alternatively, you could set your element to use static names.

```
<input id="dp1" type="text" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

(but dont do both)

Answer (score 0):

something out of the box.

Make it simple mate - use DateTime from Html5

```
<form>
  Birthday (date and time):
  <input type="datetime" name="bdaytime">
</form>
```